# Why does my registry reading function in c++ return incorrect strings?

Tags: c++, registry

I have a function which I will show at the end which is asked to retrieve a value from the registry and return it in the form of a string. If the value was "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" the function returns the string as "acegikmoqsuwy". Any help would be appreciated.

```
string Tools::ReadRegValue(HKEY root, string key, string name)
{
    HKEY hKey;
    if (RegOpenKeyEx(root, key.c_str(), 0, KEY_READ, &hKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        throw "Could not open registry key";

    DWORD type;
    DWORD cbData;
    if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, name.c_str(), NULL, &type, NULL, &cbData) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        throw "Could not read registry value";
    }

    if (type != REG_SZ)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        throw "Incorrect registry value type";
    }

    string value(cbData / sizeof(wchar_t), L'\0');
    if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, name.c_str(), NULL, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&value[0]), &cbData) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        throw "Could not read registry value";
    }

    RegCloseKey(hKey);

    size_t firstNull = value.find_first_of('\0');
    if (firstNull != string::npos)
        value.resize(firstNull);

    return value;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you carefully scrutinize where you're using wide-char semantics and APIs, where you're not, and where you're not but should be. And FYI, if you post Windows API code in a question, and said-code is not character-set-specified (ex: using `RegQueryValueEx` rather than `RegQueryValueExA` or `RegQueryValueExW`), be *certain* to specify, [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59003786/edit), how you're compiling your code (unicode vs multibyte/narrow)

Comment: `string value(cbData / sizeof(wchar_t), L'\0');` looks wrong

Comment: @Thomas is correct. Everything in this code is based on ANSI not Unicode, so the code needs to use `sizeof(char)` (1) instead of `sizeof(wchar_t)` (2), and remove the `L` prefix from `'\0'`. And also beware that the data will *usually* be null terminated, so the null will have to be removed manually when converting the data to `std::string`. I wouldnt use `value.find_first_of('\0')` for that, though. You already know the size of the data, so just check if the last char is null and if so then decrement the size before converting to `std::string`